# Customize JTaskPaneGroup/JTaskPane Header to Add a Second Image Icon

Tags: java

I was reading through the article [here](http://javaswingcomponents.blogspot.com/2011/05/using-taskpane-in-java.html) about JTaskPane.

I want to add an image icon close to the expanding/collapsing icon, instead of the default icon on the left of the title ('Product' as shown in the below image).

[image]

I found that I can remove the default icon by passing null to the setIcon method.

```
JTaskPaneGroup ProductMenu = new JTaskPaneGroup();               
ProductMenu.setTitle("Product");
ProductMenu.setIcon(null);
```

Any idea how  I could add a new icon close to the expanding/collapsing icon as follows?

[image]

Comment: The `JTaskPaneGroup` does not appear to be part of standard Swing libraries, but if you can gain access to the title component, then you should be able to edit it just like any JLabel, and you could even perform custom painting as necessary. If JTaskPaneGroup extends a Swing component, then you can further extended it and attempt to override the paintCompoent method and see if you have any luck with it, although that will only work if it's child components don't pant over the space you want to place your icon.

Comment: this looks like l2fprod? if so, please add the tag. Afair, two icons (in addition to the expand/collapse icon) are not supported. You probably have to extend its uidelegate to achieve what you want .

Comment: [JavaFX](https://openjfx.io/) has the [TitledPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/accordion-titledpane.htm) component which I believe is more versatile and therefore more appropriate to your requirements. Perhaps consider using JavaFX rather than _Swing_.